# Difference between "work" and "labour" in 1 Thessalonians 1:3

Tags: word-study, 1-thessalonians, pastorals

[1 Thessalonians 1:3](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Thessalonians%201:3&version=NIV1984) states (NIV):

> We continually remember before our God and Father your **work** produced by faith, your **labour** prompted by love, and your endurance inspired by hope in our Lord Jesus Christ.

I've checked it in several translations and most of them use these words. Only the [Amplified version](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Thessalonians%201:3&version=AMP) gave me a clue:

> Recalling unceasingly before our God and Father your **work** energized by faith and **service** motivated by love and unwavering hope in [the return of] our Lord Jesus Christ (the Messiah).

This implies to me one of two options. Either:

1. work is secular; service is Christian / church work or
2. work is your day job, service is providing help to those in need.

What is the difference here between these two very similar words, *work* and *labour*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We remember before our God and Father your work produced by faith, your labor prompted by love, and your endurance inspired by hope in our Lord Jesus Christ.

In the Greek 'work' (εργου) signifies external 'acts' done by people, which can be good or evil.  In contrast to this 'labour' (κοπου) does not focus on the 'thing' itself but in the 'effort' behind it. In this context love is the striving motive spent in the production of a 'work'

It seems therefore that Paul is bringing in the 'faith, love and hope' aspect of Christian living in connection with deeds, effort and endurance.  Faith is invisible but what we believe becomes evident to others by what we do and say.  Love is motivating so it propels us to face the task and strive to achieve our hearts desire.  Hope gives us strength to endure resistance when faith is tested because we know our effort will not go to waste as the future will be glorious and much better than today. Hope makes us courageous and optimistic.

Answer (score 0):

Work produced out of faith is in anticipation of some reward. Labor prompted by love is with out expecting any reward, it is like doing some thing to some one out of love like we do to our children, friends etc and finally we go on doing (enduring) work and lobor unceasingly because of our hope in our Lord Jesus Christ

Comment: I'm very grateful for your participation here. We're a little different from a forum, so do take the [site tour](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) if you haven't already. Answers are expected to have informed argument, cite evidence (primary and secondary). Please keep in mind that [this is not a Christian site](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/441/423). Be sure to [check out what makes us different from other sites that study the Bible](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/803/423).

Answer (score 0):

Work is a task that doesn't require experience. You get paid now for the job. Labor is a continuing task requiring the right attitude to get the reward. God see the motive behind the action. We can fool our natural supervisor, but not God. God wants laborers who will do what is required in the right spirit.

Comment: It would be necessary to reference the Greek, here, to arrive at a definitive answer (I would say).

Comment: Welcome to BH.SE! Please [take the tour](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a feel for how the site functions. Your answer hasn't addressed the question that was asked. The question is about "work" and "labour" as it is used in 1 Thessalonians 1:3. If what you say is relevant to this verse, then show how it is connected.